# Как поместить объекты enum в коллекцию?

Tags: java, android, коллекции, enum

Есть объекты enum, надо их поместить в коллекцию.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyEnum> enumCollection = Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values());
    for (MyEnum myEnum :enumCollection) {
        System.out.println(myEnum); // A B C D E
    }

}

enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В Java Collections API присутствуют реализации EnumSet и EnumMap, которые помимо стандартных методов соответствующих интерфейсов содержат удобные методы для создания коллекций на базе перечислимых типов:

```
EnumSet<MyEnum> enumSet = EnumSet.allOf(MyEnum.class);
enumSet = EnumSet.range(MyEnum.B, MyEnum.D);
enumSet = EnumSet.of(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.C, MyEnum.E);
...
EnumMap<MyEnum, Integer> enumMap = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);
enumMap.put(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.A.ordinal());
```